# Maven/Tycho - how to build both executable jar and Eclipse application based on same dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have a following structure:

```
core module A
module B depending from A
```

(Currently A and B are Eclipse plugin projects with pom.xml in them) Need to have:

1. Simple java jar console app dependent on B
2. Eclipse plugin C havingEclipse-based UI depending on B
3. RCP application using C.

I want to build all this stuff using 1-2 commands, without manual work like copying smth, exporting etc.

Tried different approaches, e.g. based on `maven-dependency-plugin` `copy-libraries` - applications can be run from Eclipse, but not able to build them.

What will be the correct approach in such a situation?

Comment: You talk about Maven modules, not about JPMS modules (you do not have any `module-info.java` files), right? The plug-in JARs (2./3.) can also be used in a plain Java application (1.) without modification. If using Tycho, dependencies are resolved via p2 (target platform or directly p2 update sites) which can not be mixed with normal Maven dependencies. (Maven dependencies are resolved at build time. In contrast, in OSGi/Eclipse bundles/plug-ins can be installed/uninstalled/updated/started/stopped at run time and therefore dependencies also have to be resolved on run time.)

Comment: Yes, I talk about Maven modules, having pom.xml and, as OSGI bundle, MANIFEST.MF

Comment: What is stopping you from using the JARs built with Tycho in your console application? Or do you want to publish the JARs as artifacts into a Maven repository?

Comment: Such approach basically works, but the problem is - if I try to use jar-with-dependencies assembly for console app, resulting jar is huge, containing both dependency jar's in lib/ folder and "flattened" dependency classes. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In OSGi dependencies are specified and resolved differently than for a non-OSGi Java application: `MANIFEST.MF` at run time vs. classpath or a JAR with all dependencies at build time. It might or might not the same JARs required in both worlds. Since there is nothing like a jar-with-dependencies in the OSGi world, Tycho cannot do that. You'll have to write and maintain something extra for that.

Comment: I don't try to build console app with Tycho - I'm trying to build it as simple jar.
Besides that I need to build Eclipse app with Tycho depending on same core code. So, no way to do this without writing some custom Maven plugin?

Comment: No custom Maven plug-in is required for that, but two `pom.xml` files are required and the dependencies have to specified twice: via `MANIFEST.MF` for Tycho to get the required JARs from p2 repositories and via a regular `pom.xml` to get the required JARs from Maven repositories or directories. If you know which JARs from the Tycho build need to be merged into a fat JAR for the console app, you might do this with the AntRunner Maven plug-in (in a single `pom.xml`).